# Defined array's length returns 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I've been trying to make a little script that both sets the color and the id of an element, but when I tried making an array of the elements, the array.length returns 0:

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var maintabArr = [];
var subtabArr = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    //replacing the navplaceholder with navbar
  $.get("http://link.link/navbar.html", function(data) {
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
  });

  maintabArr = document.getElementsByName("maintab");
  subtabArr = document.getElementsByName("subtab");

  console.log(maintabArr);
  console.log(subtabArr);
  console.log(maintabArr.length);
  console.log(subtabArr.length);

  for(var i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){    
    maintabArr[i].style = "background-color: rgb(" + maintabArr[i].bgcolor + ");";
    console.log(i);
  }

  for(i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){  
    maintabArr[i].id = maintabArr[i].name;
    console.log(i);
  }

  for(i=0;i<subtabArr.length;i++){  
    subtabArr[i].id = subtabArr[i].name;
    console.log(i);
  }

  for(i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){
    console.log("Name: " + maintabArr[i].name + ", Name's var type: " + typeof maintabArr[i].name + " | Bgcolor: " + maintabArr[i].bgcolor + ", Bgcolor's var type: " + typeof maintabArr[i].bgcolor);
    console.log(i);
  }
  for(i=0;i<subtabArr.length;i++){
    console.log("Name: " + subtabArr[i].name + ", Name's var type: " + typeof subtabArr[i].name + " | Bgcolor: " + subtabArr[i].bgcolor + ", Bgcolor's var type: " + typeof subtabArr[i].bgcolor);
    console.log(i);
  }
 });
```

navbar-HTML, this get's imported into the main HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a bgcolor="255,0,0" href="http://link.link/" name="maintab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="255,0,0" href="http://link.link/#games" name="subtab">Games</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="255,0,0" href="http://link.link/#movies" name="subtab">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="255,0,0" href="http://link.link/#about" name="subtab">About</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="0,0,255" href="http://link.link/apps.html" name="maintab">Apps</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="0,255,0" href="http://link.link/forum.html" name="maintab">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="0,255,0" href="http://link.link/forum.html#FAQ" name="subtab">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="160,82,45" href="http://link.link/log.html" name="maintab">LOG</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="166,157,184" href="http://link.link/homework.html" name="maintab">HW</a></li>
    <li><a bgcolor="213,187,107" href="http://link.link/homework.html" name="maintab">PO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now when I go onto my site and look in the console it says that both arrays have a length of 0.

Please help

Comment: Is your navbar `$("#nav-placeholder")` being populated ? It's working fine.

Comment: By the time you call the getElementsByName function, your get call to navbar.html hasn't finished yet probably (default behaviour of the function is async). You need to put all your further code in a success callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is probably that `$.get` is asynchronous which means that the code below it can execute before the callback function. Just move your functionality into that function and it should work.

```
var maintabArr = [];
var subtabArr = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    //replacing the navplaceholder with navbar
  $.get("http://link.link/navbar.html", function(data) {
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);

    maintabArr = document.getElementsByName("maintab");
    subtabArr = document.getElementsByName("subtab");

    console.log(maintabArr);
    console.log(subtabArr);
    console.log(maintabArr.length);
    console.log(subtabArr.length);

    for(var i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){    
      maintabArr[i].style = "background-color: rgb(" + maintabArr[i].bgcolor + ");";
      console.log(i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){  
      maintabArr[i].id = maintabArr[i].name;
      console.log(i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<subtabArr.length;i++){  
      subtabArr[i].id = subtabArr[i].name;
      console.log(i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<maintabArr.length;i++){
      console.log("Name: " + maintabArr[i].name + ", Name's var type: " + typeof maintabArr[i].name + " | Bgcolor: " + maintabArr[i].bgcolor + ", Bgcolor's var type: " + typeof maintabArr[i].bgcolor);
      console.log(i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<subtabArr.length;i++){
      console.log("Name: " + subtabArr[i].name + ", Name's var type: " + typeof subtabArr[i].name + " | Bgcolor: " + subtabArr[i].bgcolor + ", Bgcolor's var type: " + typeof subtabArr[i].bgcolor);
      console.log(i);
    }

  });

 });
```